# Is there a portable class library profile which supports System.Xml.Linq and System.Windows for .NET 4.0

Tags: portable-class-library

I've been working with the Portable Class Libaries using the Visual Studio 11 Beta release.

I've had quite a lot of success getting WP7, Silverlight and .Net 4.5 working together within "Profile104".

However, I've not found a way to get .Net 4 supported within the same or similar profile. In particular, I'm looking for a profile where System.Xml.Linq and System.Windows.Input.ICommand are available?

Is there any way to do this? Either by using a standard profile, or by creating my own profile and then adding type forwarding?

Thanks

Stuart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, ICommand (as well as INotifyCollectionChanged and ObservableCollection) is not available in a portable library that targets a version of .NET before 4.0.  We had to make some changes in .NET to support it (mainly adding System.Windows.dll with type forwards), which aren't available on earlier versions.

I believe System.Xml.Linq is available for portable libraries on .NET 4.0.3 and above.

Comment: In Visual Studio 11 you need to select '.net framework 4 platform update 3 or higher' on the 'change target frameworks' form in order to use System.Xml.Linq. Just .net framework 4 is not enough. Perhaps you need to run the platform update.